# How to reassign different CSV column values from different columns to a new CSV column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, scrapy

I've coded a fully functioning **web scraping software** (scrapy) that produces **real estate data** as a CSV file. For the most part, I could treat the data in python for it to be compliant with Jamovi (stats) format requirements.

I have an issue however: There are **25 CSV columns that hold many different types** of residential unit features (AC, Parking space, Terrace, Balcony, etc.).

[Unsorted CSV columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBEUX.png)
[Target CSV column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jegpR.png)

So far, my code works as follows:

```
column_1=(df['CSV_Col1_Name'])
AC_list=[]

for row in column_1:
    if row == 'Air Conditioned'
    AC_list.append(row)
    else:
     null=('null')
    AC_list.append(null)

df['AC LIST'] = np.array(AC_list)
df.to_csv("My_Data.csv",index=False) #CSV file already indexed
```

This accomplishes the purpose of creating a new column within my CSV file that runs from the first index item to the last:

```
null
null
null
[...]
Air Conditioned
null
null
Air Conditioned
```

However, I remain stuck when I need to repeat the process for all remaining 24 columns. My goal is that IF each of the CSV column row holds 'Air Conditioned', then the string is appended to my AC_list and in place of a 'null' value (in my CSV columns, each line/residential unit can only hold at most 1 AC occurrence).

I've tried to repeat the process as such:

```
column_2=(df['CSV_Col2_Name'])
AC_list=[]

for row in column_2:
    if row == 'Air Conditioned'
    AC_list.append(row)
    else:
       continue

df['AC LIST'] = np.array(AC_list)
```

But the following error is being returned: **ValueError: Length of values (258) does not match length of index (229)**. I understand that this has to do with the fact that I do not specify an append value in AC_list in case row != 'Air Conditioned', because I only want 'null' values to be replaced with 'Air Conditioned' values.

This is mind boggling to say the least hehe I've made a lot of progress in python, but restructuring data is still new to me. Any idea on how to fix the problem? :)

Thanks in advance and merry Xmas to those who celebrate it.

Kind regards,
Dan San!

Comment: Could you provide a small (eg 3 columns, 4 rows) example data and your expected output? It is unclear to me what you want to do.

Comment: Make sure to have a look at `np.where` (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and `pd.Series.where` (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html). They seem like they could help.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Chrysophylaxs :)

Thanks a lot for your input. My apologies, my question was badly sentenced. I finally found the solution. Basically, I wanted that for value *x* in column A, column B would be appended on the same row value *y*.

To do that, I used **df.loc**:

```
df.loc[df['Column_A']=='ValueX','Column B']='ValueY'
```

Example:

**INPUT**

```
Column_A      Column_B
Banana
Strawberry
Kiwi          
Tomatoe
Kiwi

df.loc[df['Column_A']=='Kiwi','Column B']='Green'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Column_A      Column_B
Banana
Strawberry
Kiwi          Green      
Tomatoe
Kiwi          Green
```

I think this solves it :)